# Communication between my react-native file and server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, backend

I'm working on a project with react native, express and MongoDB.
When I click the submit button, I want my string to be passed to server.js where I can implement my get-request. Basically, I'm unable to create communication between react-native-js file and node-js file. I'm using react-native-router-flux for navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedure One : you need to develop the backend using node+express 
the backend should expose the api endpoints like this ->
http://serverRunningurl/auth/usersignin

Procedure Two : you need to access those endpoints via your react-native side..
lots of client side http libraries out there , use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios),

Try this reference first : [The MERN Stack Tutorial](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-2-637f337e5d61)